# IE9 overflow issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have a little issue w/ an element displaying in IE9

the structure:

```
<div id="container">
    <a id="logo" href="#">stuff here</a>
</div>
```

the problem is that the container has a height of 47px and the anchor has a height of 65px. In chrome, ff, opera etc the overflow of the anchor is visible but cut off in IE9.

this is the css for the container and anchor

```
#container{
    width:100%;
    height:47px;
    overflow visible;
}

#logo{
    background:url('path/to/myimage');
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:65px;
}
```

and this displays great in everything except IE... any ideas? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must to declare Doctype For IE all versions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1    /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#container{
    width:100%;
    height:47px;
    border:1px solid red;

}

#logo{
    background:url('path/to/myimage');
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:65px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <a id="logo" href="#">stuff here</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```